# How to get CSS values from Vue component?

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm trying to get `css` values from `vue` component. What I want is to receive the css of vue component in string format like this

```
"#about {
    margin: 70px;
}
#header {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#sub-header {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.text {
    border: 1px solid #4caf50;
}"
```

In my case `document.styleSheets` doesn't do the job. I need some other way go get css from vue component.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/stanimirsp5/so4wrkfL/1/) is sample template from which I'm trying to get css:

```
<template>
    <div id="about">
        <div id="header">This is an about page</div>
        <div id="sub-header">CSS Margins</div>

        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id dictum nisi. </div>
        <br>
        <div class="text">Pellentesque vehicula sollicitudin nisl, vitae feugiat justo condimentum vel. Integer tellus nisi, porttitor sit amet sodales sit amet, imperdiet a nisl.</div>
    </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
#about {
    margin: 70px;
}
#header {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#sub-header {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.text {
    border: 1px solid #4caf50;
}
</style>
```

Comment: How/where do you want to use the CSS? Inside the Vue component or outside it?

Comment: @Hannah, I will use css outside of the vue component. My end goal is to get css and html from the vue component, compose them and create pdf from it.

Comment: You could store the styles in a separate file and import them in your component and where you want to create your PDF. But couldn't you use a library like jsPDF and just generate your PDF directly from your Vue component? Like this person has done https://codepen.io/maga18/pen/WgdqyW

Comment: As an alternative to jsPDF, I can suggest the usage of iframes: you put your pdf using vue-router to a separate page and then put the page's link to the iframe. Then you can print the page with `document.querySelector('#iframe_id').contentWindow.print()`